# Inserting item into map, which holds 2 more map

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert an item, into a map, which holds two other map.

```
map< map<int, int> , map<int, int> > GC;

map<int, int> A;
A.insert(pair<int,int>(1,1));
map<int, int>:: iterator p1 = A.begin();

map<int, int> B;
B.insert(pair<int,int>(2,3));
map<int, int>:: iterator p2 = B.begin();

GC.insert( pair< map<int,int>, map<int,int> > (*p1, *p2) );
```

Well, as presumed its not working.

How to do it?

**EDIT:**
It gives the following error:

> E:\CB\test.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to `'std::pair<std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >, std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > >::pair(std::pair<const int, int>&, std::pair<const int, int>&)'`

Comment: Maps work with Keys and Values. Do you really intend to use a map as a key? That seems strange to me, though perhaps you have a valid reason for wanting to do so. If you explain what problem you are trying to solve we may be able to help you design a better data structure for it.

Comment: This is some wicked pseudo code. IIRC there is no operator< or std::less<std::map<...>> specialization. Therefore, you'll not get lucky stuffing them in an ordered container

Comment: I am trying to write a graph class on my own. The structure I want to make is a < map<keyValue, VertexIndexValue>, map<(EdgeWeight1,VertexIndexValue1), (EdgeWeight2,VertexIndexValue2)......> ; keyValue is for some temporary storage, say when we need to set some values to the vertex in Dijkstra algorighm. Say, we are starting with vertex A,  which is connected with vertex B(alphabetic order 2) & C(3) with weight 15 & 20. Then the data I want to store is like > (0,1),{(15,3),(20,4)}

Comment: 0,1 -> 0 for the starting node, 1 for A (Alphabetic order)

Comment: @Nathanael: no, there is nothing that could justify sticking a map as a key of another map. And as for why the code is not working, sehe is right. One could implement such Comparator for his/her map and instatiate the other map with the Comparator class as the third template argument in order to make this work. But it's nonsense.

Comment: second part is what vertex A is connected with, sorry there is a typo, it will be > (15, 2) , (20, 3) - means, A is connected with B, with an edge weight 15 and C with edge weight 20.

Comment: @iamcreasy, What's not working? This is a very badly written question. Is it compiling? What error message do you get if not? Please rewrite your qeustion.

Comment: @iamcreasy : If this is intended to represent some graph data structure, you'd be **much** better off using a proper graph library e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)...

Comment: @ildjarn Actually I am trying to implement a tiny graph library on my own. I know its gonna suck, but still , just trying to do something that I haven't done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are trying to achieve here .....

Your key and value needs to be an map object in order to work...
In that case only possibility is

```
GC.insert( pair< map<int,int>, map<int,int> > (A,B) );
```

Comment: `make_pair` is quite useful. You answer could be written as `GC.insert( make_pair (A,B) );`

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want a Node class with a list/vector of Edge objects. Each Edge object would contain the edge weight and a pointer to the Node that edge connected to.

There may be better ways to create a graph than I have described, but this should get you thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
map<keyValue, VertexIndexValue>, map<(EdgeWeight1,VertexIndexValue1), (EdgeWeight2,VertexIndexValue2)......>
```

I think what you want is to use a structure as the second element of your map.  It gives you the chance to hold whatever you want in the map without it getting confusing.

```
struct sMapValue
{
   int mVertIndex;
   map<int, int>  mVertEdgeMap;
};

map< int, sMapValue> GC;
```